# htaccess from www to non-www

Tags: .htaccess, web

i'm having a problem.

I have a Python(Django) website, and i want to delete the "www" from the url, so i have this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?(.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works, but the problem is if i enter an url like "www.domain.com/admin" or "www.domain.com/something" it redirects to "domain.com" instead of "domain.com/admin" or "domain.com/something".

Do you know what is wrong with my htaccess?

Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Change `^(/)?(.*)` to `^/?(.*)`. You're capturing that `/` and appending it onto your url, instead of the part you actually want to append with `$1`.